# Possible to upload file and parse the json result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cgi, http-post

I have a form that is used to upload the file and a CGI program in the server side to process the uploaded file. The file will be renamed to a different file name that I want to pass back to the client, I want to use JSON to return the result, but the browser always prompts me to save the returnd document to a file...

Conclusion: I want to upload a file and from the HTTP response I want to parse it to get the new filename generated by server side.

```
        <form action="/a.bc?cmd=upload&user_name=binc2&size=100&type=normal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="image">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="text" value="ade75596e1d9a04d4ae0c1e81aa8fcf0" name="key" />
        </form>
```

The post will get a JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like youre not actually making an ajax request... youre being prompted to download because the header is (and should be) `application/json`. If youre not executing an ajax request or consumign the response with some other script then there is no reason to use json, jsut render whatever you want rendered.

Also you cant upload files directly with ajax. if you need to do this, do a search for "ajax upload" for various techniques.

Comment: Is it possible to post a file using AJAX .ajax() call? I guess browser will not allow that because this may have security holes.

Comment: Nope, you need to use a workaround (actually in some browsers you can do it natively, but not in all, so you generally have to have a fallback for those other browsers) the most common is to use a hidden iframe. There are also several jquery plugins that address it in different ways: http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/